# How to avoid my swf to be cached?

Tags: actionscript-3, caching, flash

How to avoid my swf to be cached in memory?, I read that I have to use something like this:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

Thats all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using get param to avoid cacheing, like myswf.swf?date or myswf.swf?random

I m using swfobject for loading swf to html pages. Here an example for you.

"myContent.swf?"+Math.random()*321 -> this makes swf to no cache.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>SWFObject dynamic embed - step 3</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf?"+Math.random()*321, "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0");
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myContent">
      <p>Alternative content</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[SWFOBJECT link](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation)

Comment: Can you please expand your answer ? thanks. Im embedding the swf object through Flash Builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the expires header with a date that has already passed:

```
<!-- BEGIN INSERT --> 
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="Mon, 04 Dec 1999 21:29:02 GMT">
<!-- END INSERT -->
```

but yep, that's all!